# Notifying Xamarin Android UI from a GcmListenerService

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

It seems that there is no easy way to communicate with the UI in the GcmListenererService, as I described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570939/xamarin-null-reference-exception-while-trying-to-display-a-toast-or-start-an-a).

Now I'm asking whether there would be any indirect way to notify the UI about incoming messages from the GcmListenerService, such as some sort of local notifications. I tried to bind the service to the UI, but the GcmListenerService lacks the OnBind overridable method.

Here's my code, I've only been able to log the message info thus far, which is not terribly useful for the end users. It kind of sucks if there is no way to inform the UI about push messages.

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        string msg = data.GetString("message");

        Log.Info("GcmLstnrService", "From: " + from);
        Log.Info("GcmLstnrService", "Msg: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Btw, it's really easy and straightforward to e.g. display a popup in the iOS and Win Phone applications when the push message arrives, but this seems to be really hard to implement in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party library messaging tool to do that. [TinyMessenger](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger/wiki) is a good and easy one to use for Xamarin. (Assuming you are using Dependency injection.)

In your GCMListerner class you can have:

```
var resolvedHub = container.Resolve<ITinyMessengerHub>();
```

and when the push notification arrives you would do:

```
resolvedHub.PublishAsync(new MyMessage());
```

and then in the UI Class where you want to do some UI Logic:

```
resolvedHub.Subscribe<MyMessage>((m) => { MessageBox.Show("Message Received"); }, true);
```

Comment: What is the container object there and how can I access it?

Comment: The container stand for inversion of control container. Long story short it is a way to resolve dependencies by keeping things loosely coupled. more info here http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @UrticaDioica you are welcome, please remember to upvote if the answer has helped you.